WooCommerce Setting Shipping Via WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array()) Not Updating Cart Totals
function mytest_set_shipping_method( $checkout ) {
    // Get shipping data
    $shipping_data = mytest_get_shipping_methods();

    // Set shipping method based on that
    if ( $shipping_data['is_free'] == true ) {
        WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array( "free_shipping:" . $shipping_data['free_shipping_instance_id'] ) );
    } else {
        WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array( "flat_rate:" . $shipping_data['flat_rate_instance_id'] ) );
    }

    // Recalculate totals after setting the shipping method
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_shipping_form', 'mytest_set_shipping_method' );

I've added the above to and hook to my functions.php file. I see in the session that the "chosen_shipping_methods" value is set, but I can not get the cart totals to recalculate with the flat_rate value of $12.00 dollars.
How can I dynamically set the shipping method and then have it recalculate the correct totals?
Current Output:
Subtotal
$51.90
Flat-Rate Shipping
$12.00
Tax
$0.00
Total
$51.90
I tried adding the above code to different hooks. I have verified that the chosen_shipping_methods is being set correctly in the session.

You should provide all related code like mytest_get_shipping_methods() function code and more details about your shipping settings… See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example…
